# Exchanging a node in Guava MutableValueGraph

Tags: guava, kotlin

I'm hitting a wall in trying to replace an element in a `com.google.common.graph.MutableValueGraph`.

I need to update element state (something I know [the docs](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/GraphsExplained#graph-elements-nodes-and-edges) advise to be careful about) on the following data class:

```
data class Frame(val method: String, val merged: Boolean = false)
```

Since graphs don't offer a method to exchange a node for another, I rolled my own:

```
fun MutableValueGraph<Frame, Int>.exchangeNode(old: Frame, new: Frame): Boolean {
    if (old == new) return true

    if (isDirected) {
        this.predecessors(old).forEach { 
            this.putEdgeValue(it, new, this.edgeValue(it, old)) }
        this.successors(old).forEach { 
            this.putEdgeValue(new, it, this.edgeValue(old, it)) }
    } else {
        this.adjacentNodes(old).forEach { 
            this.putEdgeValue(it, new, this.edgeValue(it, old)) }
    }
    return this.removeNode(old)
}
```

However, I hit a ConcurrentModificationException:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextNode(HashMap.java:1437)
at java.util.HashMap$EntryIterator.next(HashMap.java:1471)
at java.util.HashMap$EntryIterator.next(HashMap.java:1469)
at com.google.common.graph.DirectedGraphConnections$1$1.computeNext(DirectedGraphConnections.java:113)
at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.tryToComputeNext(AbstractIterator.java:145)
at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.hasNext(AbstractIterator.java:140)
at TestKt.exchangeNode(Test.kt:292)
...
```

Sounds fair as I'm exchanging a bunch of nodes in a for loop, probably trying to touch a adjacent node that has already been exchanged?

My question is: how do I replace multiple nodes in a ValueGraph, keeping their edge values?

Comment: For the time being, I do what Guava's docs say and track the mutable state in an extra data structure. The question still has value on it's own, I think.

Answer (score 0):

A less efficient approach but one that should certainly avoid `ConcurrentModificationException` is to induce a subgraph from the relevant nodes and then removing the old node and adding the new and finally using the induced subgraph to add the edge values back in:

```
fun MutableValueGraph<Frame, Int>.exchangeNode(old: Frame, new: Frame): Boolean {
    if (old == new) return false

    val inducedSubgraph = Graphs.inducedSubgraph(this, adjacentNodes(old) + old)

    removeNode(old)
    addNode(new)

    if (isDirected) {
        for (predecessor in inducedSubgraph.predecessors(old)) {
            putEdgeValue(predecessor, new, inducedSubgraph.edgeValue(predecessor, old))
        }
        for (successor in inducedSubgraph.successors(old)) {
            putEdgeValue(new, successor, inducedSubgraph.edgeValue(old, successor))
        }
    } else {
        for (adjacentNode in inducedSubgraph.adjacentNodes(old)) {
            putEdgeValue(adjacentNode, new, inducedSubgraph.edgeValue(adjacentNode, old))
        }
    }

    return true
}
```